# UICollectionView 'fly in' effect

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've been looking all over the internet for this animation. When you unlock your iPhone the icons 'fly in' from the outside of the screen to their spots. Does anyone know where I can find a link on how to implement this in my UICollectionView as the cells load?

Comment: A few thoughts: 1 Springboard might not use UICollectionView; 2 try animating the spacing between the cells -- horizontal and vertical -- from something big to what you want it to be. Bonus points for varying alpha inversely.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a screen recording of the Springboard (the iOS desktop) and it looks to me like it just uses an animation of the scale transform and the center transform to zoom in/zoom out on the selected icon. This would be trivial to do using either CAAnimation or a UIView animation.